# error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 23.10

I downloaded the .deb package with Haroopad from the developers website:
http://pad.haroopress.com/user.html
It installs without problems, with QApt Package Installer, but when running it gives the following error:

```
/usr/share/haroopad/haroopad: error while loading shared libraries: 
libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched for an answer and found this one that made sense to me:
Install the libgconf-2-4 package containing libgconf-2.so.4.

But I got this negative result:

```
   $> sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
```

The answer I got was:

```
> Creating dependency tree... Done
> Reading status information... Done
> E: Could not locate package libgconf-2-4
```

Im working on:
Kubuntu 23.10 x86_64
Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X (16) @ 3.800GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1630
Memory: 4009MiB / 31996MiB

Comment: AFAIK `gconf` has been deprecated for some time - `libgconf-2-4` was provided up to Ubuntu 23.04 for legacy application compatibility but appears to have been dropped altogether from 23.10. The software's maintainers should consider [Migrating to gsettings](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/migrating-gconf.html)

Comment: If what you say is true, and I don't doubt it, what I need download the package from somewhere and put it in the right place.  Could ir break something at 23.10 instalation?
Has anyone already done that, or can you give me some ideas on how to do it? 
Is that package in the repositories of previous versions?

Comment: Yes the package is in earlier repositories, most recently [Package: libgconf-2-4 (3.2.6-8ubuntu1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/libgconf-2-4). I don't know if installing it will break other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Solution

I downloaded the libgconf-2-4 package and the package installer does not install it.
I unpacked the .deb in ~/Downloads/ and the two packages it contains, *control.tar.xz* and *data.tar.xz* in the created directory.
The *data.tar.xz* package contains the installable files in a structure like the following:

```
>-usr/
   |_lib/
   |  |_x86_64-linux-gnu/
   |     |_libgconf-2.so.4
   |     |_libgconf-2.so.4.5
   |     
   |_share/
      |_doc/
```

I have just copied the two library files. Really the first one is a link to the second one:

```bash
$> sudo cp libgconf-2.so.4 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$> sudo cp libgconf-2.so.4 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I checked that they had 'arrived' at their destination:

```bash
$> cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$> ls -al libgconf*.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200128 ene  9 10:56 libgconf-2.so.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200128 ene  9 10:57 libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
```

And I ran Haroopad from the terminal, which gave me the following error message:

```bash
$ haroopad
[5735:0109/111207:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(162)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[5735:0109/111207:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(190)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
[5759:0109/111239:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1408)] X error received: serial 1264, error_code 3 (BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)), request_code 4, minor_code 0
```

I have not checked and installed the depends files for libgconf-2.so.4 listed in
https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/libgconf-2-4
I was expecting to receive error messages about this and then proceed. I haven't installed them at first because I don't know how it might affect the system, as they are old libraries and might conflict with updated libraries that perform the same task.

I feel that I have started to 'live dangerously' and like the Gauls in "Asterix" and like them, I am afraid that "the sky is falling on our heads". But as Caesar would say, "Alea jacta est".

I think this might be an answer to "how to install the missing libgconf-2.so.4 file in Ubuntu 23.10" and that the problems encountered, should be the subject of another question.

Thanks to the users who have helped me.